# Find nearest start/end geometry to lines

Tags: qgis, overlay

I have two layers: 'markers' is a points layer  and 'projects' is a a set of lines (orange in the map below). I need to create two attributes, Start_Loc and End_Loc in 'projects' which are the IDs of the closest point to the start location and end location.

```
array_first(
array_remove_all( 
    array_foreach (
        overlay_nearest ('markers',$id),
        if (
            within (
                geometry (get_feature_by_id ('markers',@element)),
                buffer (start_point($geometry), 20)
            ),
            attribute (get_feature_by_id ('markers',@element), 'Start_loc'),
            ''
        )
    ),
''))
```

I think I am writing something wrong in overlay_nearest- if I run the following code in the field calculator

```
overlay_nearest('markers', max_distance:= 20)
```

the result is 1 but if I try

```
overlay_nearest('markers', expression:= $id, max_distance:= 20)
```

then the resulting values are all null. I have tried every alternative I can think of for expression but haven't been able to get even a list of ids so far. What is the correct way of doing this?

If it matters, the name of the marker points I am looking for is 'Marker_ID' but can make any unique ID work.

[image]

Answer (score 3):

it takes the field name, between double quotes:

```
overlay_nearest('markers', expression:= "Marker_ID", max_distance:= 20)
```

[image]

Comment: I have tried the field name in double quotes, single quotes, and no quotes, and still got a null value.

Comment: @Amie see the screenshot... then double check every spelling (ex: a wrong field name would result in a Null being returned)

Comment: I copy/pasted the field name and checked multiple times. I tried this both with an empty field as an int and as a string (the field in the table is a string). What I am using is below, any ideas on other issues I might look at?
overlay_nearest('markers', expression:= "Marker_ID", max_distance:= 20)